# What will happen if a grapple is no longer valid?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple

After reading [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96230/can-a-mind-flayer-tentacle-grapple-be-broken-by-the-grapplee?rq=1) I got curious about something regarding the answer. The answer dictates a mind flayer can only use it's grapple attack on medium creatures. So, what happens if the grappled creature becomes large through a spell effect or some sort of natural ability while it is grappled?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The grapple ends

Once a creature becomes an ineligible target for an effect, the effect no longer affects it.

Comment: Is there any reference you might have that backs your answer?  It's very relevant to another (practically duplicate) question I'm trying to answer.